# PHP Iterate 12 items perform echo on every third

Tags: php, iteration

Hi I have been chasing my tail for a while on this one and wondered if someone could solve my headache.

Basically I am rendering 12 items to the page. Each 3 items need to be wrapped in a row like:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
    <div class='item'>

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Hi I think some code would help:

```
$i=0;
foreach($posts as $p) {

$i++
}
```

So basically within the for each I will be outputting a row and 3 items.The results are coming from a database query. I have tried a few different approaches such as

```
if($i == 1) {echo "<div class='row'>";}
                    if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
                       echo "</div><div class='row'>";
                    }
```

However I keep failing, please note these are just snippets of code.

Comment: What does your PHP code look like?

Comment: Use two loops - one for rows and one (inner) for items.

Comment: Use a count with the `%` operator

Comment: what is the source of your items ? array? database? Some more PHP code for what you've tried so far would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two loops:

```
// Outer loop for each row
for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
    echo '<row>';

    // Inner loop for the items
    for ($item = 0; $item < 3; $item++) {
        echo '<item>';
    }

    echo '</row>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have done it yourself. it needs to know very basic of loop.
try like this:

```
for($i=0;$i <= 3; $i++){ //outer loop for 12 times
     echo "<row>"; // start row
     for ($j=0;$j<3;$j++){ // inner loops for echoing 3 times
      echo "<item>"; //echo item
     }
     echo "</row>"; // end row
    }
```

demo : https://eval.in/107129

I have used `"\n"` for new line in demo. if you needed new line then you can use `<br />`

Comment: This will produce 12 lines of `<row>`, rather than 4 as required. Should be `$i < 4`

Comment: sorry for silly mistakes. i have corrected it @Chris